# <ul> with 2 lines and <li> with border-right

Tags: html, css, html-lists, border

I got a menu and the `<li>` element has something like a border at right.

The problem about this is when it breaks for a second line of `<li>` elements. I know that i can take last-child border out, but is there a way to know when it breaks a line?

*Only with CSS and automatic, i cant use nth-child(), since i will not have the control over the categories.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/m5cy969s/ - I would like to take out the border from the third `<li>`.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>Primeiro</li>
    <li>Segundo</li>
    <li>Terceiro</li>
    <li>Quarto</li>
    <li>Quinto</li>
</ul>

ul,li { padding:0; margin: 0; }
```

CSS

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    position: relative;
}

li:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    right: -2px;
    top: 0;
    border-left: 2px solid blue;
    border-right: 2px solid green;
    height: 100%;
}

ul {
    max-width: 220px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color:pink;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/m5cy969s/3/

Comment: @dward That's the effect, I'm sure, but that's a hard-coded value not something that can happen automatically to the "end" `li` in the middle of a breaking row.

Comment: @dward i guess he wants it indep from the actual number of elements. More like "If the actual element is the last one which will be displayed in that line, remove the border"

Comment: like this then? http://jsfiddle.net/m5cy969s/5/

Comment: @dward i can't use nth-child.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this with pure CSS would be to manually select the child `<li>` that breaks at the end and remove the border. In your case, this would be the third child.

```
li:nth-child(3):after { 
    border: none 
}
```

To do this "automatically", you would need JS.

Comment: This is not what he wants? And if so it must be like this ul,li:nth-child(2){   
    border-right:0px;
}

Comment: @Patrick-Burtchaell Thanks, you are right, I would have to make by a automatic way.